# exe command seems not executed in Docker

Tags: python, windows, docker

I am trying to build windows container in which execute .exe file. The code is as below.
I could confirm this python file run .exe file since result file is generated.  However, when I build the windows container and run the docker container, exe file seems not executed since result file is not generated.
Can anyone tell me why this Dockerfile is failing to execute .exe file and how to solve this issue?

app.py

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os
import boto3
import zipfile

def main():

    #os.chdir("ecs/test/dataset")
    os.chdir("test/dataset")

    if os.path.isfile("therb.exe"):
        print("therb.exe is found")
        p = subprocess.Popen("Therb.exe",shell=True)
        p.wait()

        stdout,stderr=p.communicate()
        print('STDOUT: {}'.format(stdout))
        print('STDERR: {}'.format(stderr))

        print ("list directory after",os.listdir())
    else:
        print("therb.exe is not found")

        print ("list directory after",os.listdir())  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = main()
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:windowsservercore-1809

COPY . /app/ecs

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
RUN pip install -r ecs/requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python","ecs/app.py"]
```

Comment: That python program defines a `main()` function but never calls it...

Comment: are you copying the exe file in the directory? your script should also check if the exe exists before trying to run it

Comment: @JohnGordon I was missing some code in stack overflow. I was calling main() as above

Comment: @Mihai I have edited the code to check if the exe file exist as below code and console shows exe file exist